# How to browse sqlite file in iOS 6.1?

Tags: ios, database, macos, sqlite

My question is pretty simple and I did not find accurate answer so far.

I am using SQLite database in an application using a typical way (libsqlite3.dylib) and opening a file named `FILE_NAME.sqlite`, which I actually not placed in my xCode project. But still it is working and I am able to INSERT and SELECT records in database.

So, my question is, where that `FILE_NAME.sqlite` should be placed.

Using MAC OSX 10.8.4
iPhone SDK 6.x

Comment: Copy it from the app bundle into the documents folder: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6545180/ios-copy-a-file-in-documents-folder

Answer (score 0):

In sqlite, when you do something in a DB, if the DB doesn't exist sqlite create it for you.
If you run this application in the iOS Simulator, you can find this file in Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/6.1/Applications/(app_id)/Documents
where "(app_id)" is your application's id.

Comment: There is no directory of name "iPhone Simulator" under "Application Support". However, I found "iPhone Simulator" directory in Macintosh HD/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/SDKs/iPhoneSi‌​mulator6.1.sdk/ But where should I go after iPhoneSimulator6.1.sdk directory?

Comment: That's the incorrect directory. You have to search in Application Support folder..

Answer (score 0):

Actually,The files in app bundle cannot be changed after app installed.So you have to copy the FILE_NAME.sqlite to the document directory after app be installed.After that,you have to use the sqlite in the document directory.When you update the database in the xcode,you have to uninstall your app in the device or simulator.