# FMDB Database not working on device, but it is working in Simulator

Tags: ios, database, sqlite, fmdb

I have this database that i created, i want to load it using FMDB, but on the simulator i can query select the data, but not on the ipad.

i use this code to check it.

```
- (void)createDatabase{
    //set reference to database here

    BOOL success;
    NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
    NSError *error;
    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    // Database filename can have extension db/sqlite.
    NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString *appDBPath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"product.db"];

    success = [fileManager fileExistsAtPath:appDBPath];
    if (success) {
        [self getAllData];
        return;
    }
    // The writable database does not exist, so copy the default to the appropriate location.
    NSString *defaultDBPath = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"product.db"];
    success = [fileManager copyItemAtPath:defaultDBPath toPath:appDBPath error:&error];
    NSAssert(success, @"Failed to create writable database file with message '%@'.", [error localizedDescription]);
    [self getAllData];
}

//method used to create database and check if it exists

- (void)getAllData {
    // Getting the database path.
    NSArray  *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *docsPath = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString *dbPath = [docsPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"product.db"];

    database = [FMDatabase databaseWithPath:dbPath];
    [database open];
    NSString *sqlSelectQuery = @"SELECT * FROM Categories";

    // Query result
    FMResultSet *resultsWithNameLocation = [database executeQuery:sqlSelectQuery];
    while([resultsWithNameLocation next]) {
        NSString *strID = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",[resultsWithNameLocation intForColumn:@"id"]];
        NSString *strName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[resultsWithNameLocation stringForColumn:@"cat"]];
        NSString *strLoc = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[resultsWithNameLocation stringForColumn:@"Location"]];

        // loading your data into the array, dictionaries.
        NSLog(@"ID = %@, Name = %@, Location = %@",strID, strName, strLoc);
    }
    [database close];
}
```

i put the `product.db` in the supporting files, and i copied it in the Copy Bundle Resources for the targets. Does anyone what i am doing wrong? i am kind of at a dead end here.

Thanks in advance

The problem occurs at the selecting stage, when i select it it returns:

> "DB Error: 1 "no such table"

Comment: Could you be a little bit more specific than "not working"?

Comment: Oh sorry, when i select some values from the database it says: DB Error: 1 "no such table. And when i use the simulator it gives me the results

Comment: Did You copy database file to Document directory properly?

Comment: I placed it in the build phases underneith Copy Bundle Resources. That is the copying part right, or am i missing something? And when googling a bit it says that if the part  success = [fileManager fileExistsAtPath:appDBPath];
    if (success) { is true that it is copied properly

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6545180/ios-copy-a-file-in-documents-folder see this answer and copy your database file using this. it would be much better if you write code for copy in didFinishLaunchingWithOptions

Comment: But that's exactely whats happening here right?

success = [fileManager fileExistsAtPath:appDBPath];
    if (success) {
        [self getAllData];
        return;
    }
    // The writable database does not exist, so copy the default to the appropriate location.
    NSString *defaultDBPath = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"product.db"];
    success = [fileManager copyItemAtPath:defaultDBPath toPath:appDBPath error:&error];
    NSAssert(success, @"Failed to create writable database file with message '%@'.", [localizedDescription]);
    [self getAllData];

Comment: Wow, that actually fixed it. Write yourself an answer and i accept it.. i feel retarted

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you ever ran the app on the device before you refined the file open/copy logic, you may have accidentally created a blank database in the documents folder (because if you open a database and it's not found, it creates a blank database). Try deleting the app (which will remove any blank database that might be lingering about) and reinstalling the app and see if that fixes it.

By the way, in the future, you can avoid this problem by using [`openWithFlags`](http://ccgus.github.io/fmdb/html/Classes/FMDatabase.html#//api/name/openWithFlags:) (rather than `open`) with `SQLITE_OPEN_READWRITE` (but not `SQLITE_OPEN_CREATE`), and that will ensure that the app never creates a blank database if it doesn't find one.

You can see the [SQLite documentation](http://sqlite.org/c3ref/open.html) on `sqlite3_open` (which FMDB `open` uses) and `sqlite_open_v2` (which FMDB `openWithFlags` uses) for a discussion of these flags.